# PHP doesn't load extensions specified in php.ini, but loads with dl()

Tags: php

Php doesn't load extensions specified through php.ini

`php -v` doesn't give any errors or warnings

`php -i | grep extension_dir` shows that extension_dir is set to where extension files are, but they don't show up in extension list in `php -m`

However running `php -r 'dl("apc.so"); phpinfo();' | grep apc` shows that modules load normaly with `dl()` function.

I installed php-5.3.5 from source.
Configured with

```
'--enable-fastcgi'
'--enable-fpm'
'--enable-mbstring'
'--enable-pdo'
'--enable-inline-optimization'
'--enable-sockets'
'--enable-zip'
'--enable-mbregex'
'--enable-xml'
'--enable-sysvsem'
'--enable-sysvshm'
'--enable-pcntl'
'--enable-ftp'
'--enable-soap'
'--enable-shmop'
'--disable-rpath'
'--disable-debug'
'--with-mcrypt'
'--with-zlib'
'--with-curl'
'--with-bz2'
'--with-mysql'
'--with-gettext'
'--with-gd'
'--with-pdo-mysql'
'--with-pcre-regex'
'--with-mhash'
'--with-pic'
'--with-zlib-dir'
'--with-ttf'
'--with-openssl'
'--with-png-dir'
'--with-libdir=lib64'
'--without-pdo-sqlite'
'--without-sqlite'
```

`uname -a` prints:

```
Linux ip-*-*-*-* 2.6.34.7-56.40.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Oct 22 18:48:49 UTC 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Php runs on nginx 0.9.5 through php-fpm

Comment: The `nginx` restart scripts are not trustworthy. Kill the server, then restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort-of fixed this by statically linking extensions I needed in the php executable, everything works now. Server won't load xdebug extension though.

Comment: I have the same problem, my server does not load xdebug

Answer (score 7):

For extensions to be loaded, you must have one line such as the following one :

```
extension=apc.so
```

in the `php.ini` *(or any other `.ini` file)* file that's used by PHP.

If extensions load properly when you're using `dl()`, it means your extensions are OK *(no wrong version or anything like that)*.

The next step, so is to :

- Make sure you have added the `extension=...` lines to your `php.ini` file
- Make sure you've modified the right `php.ini` file

You can check which `php.ini` file is used : it's displayed in the ouput of `phpinfo()`.

Note : with some Linux distributions, the `php.ini` file used in CLI is not the same one as the one used with Apache *(not sure about the one used for nginx)*.

Comment: php.ini was configured properly. I also scanned the system for other php.ini files, but that was the only one.

Answer (score -1):

Go to **Php.ini** File from phpmyadmin open in text editor and search for **;extension=php_soap.dll** and just remove **;** symbol and after that **restart** your Wamp/xamp services and then **refresh** your url page..enjoy

Comment: With this module you get all the benefits of phpMyAdmin tool:

Import and export data (CSV, SQL)
Browse and manage DB tables, views, fields, indexes
Execute SQL-queries
Search in DB
And much more…
All the functionality is provided directly from the back-end of your Magento, with simple installation in minutes and is free of charge!

Comment: i know what phpmyadmin is. but what does it have to do with the OP's question?